# Modify Values in a Dictionary While Iterating Through It

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have initialized a dictionary of the form:

```
{1: 0,
 2: 0, 
 3: 0,
 .
 . 
 .
 98: 0,
 99: 0,
 100:0}
```

where i want to pass a value of 1 through it iteratively (so that every key will have a value of 1 with ascending order, while all the others have a value of 0).

My goal is to run an algorithm with this dictionary as input in every iteration.

How can i do that in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding :

```
import copy

sample_dict = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}


for k, v in sample_dict.items():
  sample_dict_loop = sample_dict.copy()
  sample_dict_loop[k] = 1
  print(sample_dict_loop)
```

Output of the `print`statement in the `loop`:

```
{1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
{1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0}
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 0}
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1}
```

NOTE: The logic I have given is creating a new `dict` in the `loop`

Comment: Given this is just a simple dictionary with integer values, I imagine `sample_dict.copy()` would suffice no?

Comment: i dint know theres a method `.copy()` . Thanks for that !!

Answer (score 2):

This will start from key `1` and change its value to `1`. Then it will go to key `2` change its value to `1` and change the value of key `1` back to `0`, and so on.

```
d = {i:0 for i in range(1, 101)}

for i in range(1, 101):
  d[i]=1
  if i>1:
    d[i-1]=0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works ! I was just trying to find something more python-like

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generator that tracks last used and current keys, yielding the dict on each change

```
def dict_sequencer(orig):
    keys = sorted(orig.keys(),reverse=True)
    key0 = keys.pop()
    orig[key0] = 1
    yield orig
    for _ in range(len(keys)):      
        key1 = keys.pop()
        orig[key0] = 0
        orig[key1] = 1
        yield orig
        key0 = key1
```

Comment: I can't follow your code very well . I'll examine it further and get back to you. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

To initialize a dictionary of nothing but zeroes:

```
d = {i: 0 for i in range(1, 101)}
```

If you wanted to take this dict and randomly set one of its elements to 1, you could do:

```
import random

d[random.choice(list(d.keys()))] = 1
```

If you wanted to do this to each in turn, but still in a random order, you could take the list of keys and `shuffle` it:

```
keys = list(d.keys())
random.shuffle(keys)
for key in keys:
    d[key] = 1
```

Comment: Shuffle reorganises my dictionary. I just want it to change in ascending order. Not randomly